# Create 10,000 non-repeating random numbers in PHP

Tags: php, random

I need to work out a way to create 10,000 non-repeating random numbers in PHP, and then put it into database table. Number will be 12 digits long.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: or maybe use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This assumes that you can generate a 12 digit random number without problems (use getrandmax() to see how big you can get....according to php.net on some systems 32k is as large a number as you can get.

```
$array = array();

while(sizeof($array)<=10000){
  $number = mt_rand(0,999999999999);
  if(!array_key_exists($number,$array)){
     $array[$number] = null;
  }
}

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  //write array records to db.
}
```

You could use either rand() or mt_rand().  mt_rand() is supposed to be faster however.

Comment: No need for doing the `in_array()`, which'd make this slow down as the number of numbers to generate increases. Just use the number as the array key, which reduces the duplicate check to `if isset($array[$number]) { ... }`

Comment: `in_array` I believe takes linear time, so this overall algorithm takes quadratic time. By saying `$array[$number] = null;` and using `array_key_exists` instead, you should have significantly better performance (close to linear).

Comment: I updated the above code to reflect to use a @Marc B's suggestion and @erisco's suggestion.

Comment: I guess "What is the best way to do this?" you didn't actually want the best way, since there are better answers here, you just wanted to be given the code without thinking about your problem. You're doomed to ignorance, boy.

Comment: The code is currently non-functional.  The second parameter to array_key_exists needs to be the array, and not a value.  The foreach also needs to be modified to get the key and not the value (using array_keys is probably best, though).

Answer (score 4):

At 12 digits long, I don't think the possibility of getting repeats is very large.  I would probably just generate the numbers, try to insert them into the table, and if it already exists (assuming you have a unique constraint on that column) just generate another one.

Comment: I was bored so I wanted to see how likely it was. Not even CLOSE to likely. With a max random of about 2 billion. I generated about a million random numbers, and didn't have one collision. I ran out of memory before I could make it happen. http://www.ideone.com/fpnZX

Answer (score 3):

Read e.g. 40000 (=PHP_INT_SIZE * 10000) bytes from `/dev/random` **at once**, then split it, modularize it (the `%` operator), and there you have it.

Then filter it, and repeat the procedure.

That avoids too many syscalls/context switches (between the php runtime, the zend engine, and the operating system itself - I'm not going to dive into details here).

That should be the most performant way of doing it.

Comment: +1 - I like the idea of using `/dev/random`.  My only concern would be about portability.  Obviously it won't work on windows, and may not work if there is an `open_basedir` restriction in effect as well.

Comment: I agree. The question doesn't mention any restriction though, so I had "my room".

Comment: Having never actually had the need to do it before, what is the most kosher way to cast a four byte chunk to an int (in PHP, that is)?

Comment: `unpack()` is the way to go. As you can imagine, performance all the way with my method. You have the repeater, so no loops in the PHP runtime, the loops are done by the CPU "directly" (through the PHP binary).

Comment: @Flavius  Sweet, I was unaware of that function.

Comment: I tested it quite a few times, it has never occured `/dev/urandom` giving me back even one duplicate number in those 10000. `/dev/random` is slow though. I could edit my answer if you want to see the POC. No loops whatsoever, just pure speed - at least on the PHP side.

Answer (score 1):

Generate 10000 random numbers and place them in an array.  Run the array through `array_unique`.  Check the length.  If less than 10000, add on a bunch more.  Run the array through `array_unique`.  If greater than 10000, then run through `array_slice` to give 10000.  Otherwise, lather, rinse, repeat.